# Почему не отображается компонент?

Tags: vue.js

Только начал изучать Vue, читаю Introduction Guide, [часть про компоненты](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components).

Почему-то у меня не получается заставить этот пример работать. Код, вроде бы, написан абсолютно верно:

```js
Vue.component("todo-item", {
    template: "<li>This is a todo</li>"
});
```

```html
<ol>
  <todo-item></todo-item>
</ol>
```

Все точно как в примере. Но компонент на странице не рендерится. Более того, ни в консоли, ни в Vue Dev Tools никаких ошибок и предупреждений нет.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как выяснилось](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805885/5899212), необходимо, чтобы `ol` находился внутри обозначенного для Vue элемента:

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>This is a list item</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <todo-item></todo-item>
  </ol>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<div>

</div>
```