# Не отображается компонент между тегами <select>...</select>

Tags: vue.js

Изучая Vue, столкнулся с проблемой. В документации есть [пример](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components) с нумерованным списком:

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<li>{{ todo.text }}</li>'
});

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Овощи'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Сыр'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Что там ещё люди едят?'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app-7">
  <ol>
    <todo-item v-for="item in groceryList" v-bind:todo="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></todo-item>
  </ol>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

[image: Вот как компилится этот пример]

Но, когда я пытаюсь перерисовать все это дело под выпадающий список `select`, то этот список не заполняется никакими данными. Переделанный мною код:

```js
// Определяем новый компонент под именем todo-item
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<option > {{ todo.text }}</option>'
});

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Овощи'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Сыр'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Что там ещё люди едят?'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app-7">
  <select>
    <todo-item v-for="item in groceryList" v-bind:todo="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></todo-item>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

Прошу найти решение и дать некоторые пояснения к данной проблеме.

Comment: Вам стоит для начала изучить html

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/755068/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации:

> Некоторые HTML-элементы, такие как `<ul>`, `<ol>`, `<table>` и `<select>` имеют ограничения на то, какие элементы могут отображаться внутри них, или например элементы, такие как `<li>`, `<tr>` и `<option>` могут появляться только внутри других определённых элементов.

Простым языком, если вы захотите вывести в `<select>` допустим `<div>`, при рендеринге страницы, `<div>`-тег не отобразится внутри `<select>`, так как это противоречит спецификации.

В нашем случае, когда происходит рендеринг, в `<select>` пытается вставится `<todo-item>`, а `<select>` в спецификации никто не предупредил, что такой можно будет вставить, вот он и игнорирует все подобные элементы и ничего не выводит в `<select>`.

Однако при создании vue, это было учтено и как отмечено в документации:

> Пользовательский компонент `<blog-post-row>`(в нашем случае `<todo-item>` - от автора) будет поднят выше(), так как считается недопустимым содержимым, вызывая ошибки в итоговой отрисовке. К счастью, специальный атрибут `is` предоставляет решение этой проблемы:

Таким образом, выполняя наставления документации меняем внутри `<select>...</select>` вместо `<todo-item ...>` -> `<option is="todo-item" ...>` мы получаем на выходе вполне рабочий `<select>`.

Использованы следующие источники информации - [Vue: Основы компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html), [Vue: Особенности парсинга DOM-шаблона](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-DOM-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

**Решение задачи автора вопроса (c использованием атрибута `is`)**

```js
// Определяем новый компонент под именем todo-item
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<option :value="todo.text">{{ todo.text }}</option>'
});

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Овощи'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Сыр'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Что там ещё люди едят?'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app-7">
  <select>
    <option v-for="item in groceryList"
      v-bind:todo="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      is="todo-item"
    ></option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

**Решение задачи автора вопроса (c использованием `<template>`)**

```js
// Определяем новый компонент под именем todo-item
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<option :value="todo.text"> {{ todo.text }}</option>'
});

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [{
      id: 0,
      text: 'Овощи'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Сыр'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Что там ещё люди едят?'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app-7">
  <select>
    <template>
      <todo-item v-for="item in groceryList"
        v-bind:todo="item"
        v-bind:key="item.id"
      ></todo-item>
    </template>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```